# Is there any complete list of open source hubs specifically designed for materials modeling and computational materials science?

Tags: databases, open-source

Several years ago, I became familiar with [nanoHUB](https://nanohub.org/) for accessing open-source codes and software specifically for computational materials science at the nano-scale as well as [PFHub](https://pages.nist.gov/pfhub/) that gives you access to phase-field and microstructural modeling codes and software. Both of these hubs are open-source and you could use other codes or share your own code there. I'm wondering if there is a more complete list of similar hubs specifically for computational materials science (for a whole range of materials modeling from atomistic, quantum mechanics, molecular dynamics to mesoscopic and even macroscopic modeling) including these two that I know. I really appreciate any recommendations or suggestions here.

Answer (score 11):

The [NIST Materials Resource Registry](https://materials.registry.nist.gov/) is not limited to computational resources, but refers to many of the codes you're looking for. Searching for "hub" only turns up two listings, both of which are tied to nanoHUB and Purdue.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I understand the meaning of hubs here. But below are some listing of databases with/without abilities to calculate/lookup materials properties.

MaterialsProject.org
Crystallography Open Database (COD)
AFLOW (http://www.aflowlib.org/)
Nomad (NOMADnomad-coe.eu)